# In C#, how to `Paket Add` dependencies to all projects in a folder even when they are in separate solutions?

Tags: c#, dependencies, nuget, roslyn-code-analysis, paket

Say I have a `packet.dependencies` file in a root folder full of different solutions adding up to hundreds of projects, each with a `paket.references` file.

Is there an easy way to go about adding the same package/same version in all the projects with a single command (or close) with paket?

In my use case, I'm trying to add an analyzer to every C# project we have. It would be tedious to add the same package and version to hundreds of different C# projects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually just `paket add <package ID>`, if ran in the root folder with the `paket.dependencies` file, it will actually find all the `.csproj` files and add the dependency.

It was the following line in the [docs](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-add.html) that threw me off:

> By default packages are only added to the solution directory, but not on any of its projects. It's possible to add the package to a specific project:

But it will actually add the dependency to all solutions and projects.